# close id with a quote - concatenation jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, string-concatenation

I have problem with concatenation a table id with a variable. The problem seems to be to close the id with a quote:

```
"
```

This is the variable

```
var mytable = $('<table id=\"paymentTable' + cnt + '\"' + '></table>')
```

The problem is to closing the id after the variable `cnt`.

In the output stream of the concatenating it looks like this:

```
<table id="paymentTable3>
```

where `3` is the `cnt`-variable.

Greatful for help!

Answer (score 2):

make it

```
var mytable = $('<table id=\"paymentTable' + cnt + '\"></table>')
```

You were closing *single quote* `'` without closing the *double quote* `"` first.

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
var mytable = $('<table id="paymentTable' + cnt + '"' + '></table>');
```

Or

```
var mytable = $("<table id='paymentTable" + cnt + "'" + "></table>");
```

Not need to escape double quote untill it is in double quotes

```
var mytable = $("<table id=\"paymentTable" + cnt + "\"" + "></table>")
```